# What's "inside" the TextField

Tags: validation, javafx

I have the following **JavaFX** code:

```
final TextField textField = new TextField();
```

and an`EventHandler<ActionEvent>`with checking textField wether it's empty or not. The problem is that `textField.getText() == null` or `textField.getText() == ""` both returns **false**, but i didn't print anything in that field, so it should return true.

```
final TextField textField = new TextField();
browse.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        File chFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(stage);
        if (chFile != null) {
            // some code
            if (textField.getText() != null && textField.getText() != "") {
                // some code
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `textField.getText()` returns a java `String`. Java `String` is an `Object` so you should use `equals()` method instead of `==` to compare Strings. `==` operator is used for comparing primitive types in Java. To understand this better, please look this [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/682495) Q/A for string comparison in Java.
As I said you can use `textField.getText().equals("")` for checking the String emptiness but the common usage for it is:

```
     if (textField.getText() != null && ! textField.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
          // some code
     }
```

where `!` is a boolean NOT operator. Also not the `trim()` method. This is for checking if the user entered whitespaces only then treat them as an empty value. Otherwise checking the whitespaces with `equals("")` will fail.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(textfield.getText().trim().length>0)
//do Something
else
//can't be blank
```